# If I drag and drop a file to "copy" it from one drive to an other, if the object drive has an identically named file, does that file get overwritten?

Tags: windows-7, windows

In Windows 7 if I drag and drop a file to "copy" it from one drive to an other, if the object drive has an identically named file, does that file get overwritten ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: The file on the destination would only get overwritten if you click "Copy and Replace"

Answer (score 1):

You will get a dialogue box asking if you want to replace it

[image]